# How can force SQL DateDiff function to stop rounding up?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query that tries to count from an exact date to an exact date. Today is 2/16/2022. Between 6/30/2020 and 2/16/2022 19 months have gone by. My DateDiff query returns 20? How can I force DateDiff function to return 19?

```
select datediff(month, '6/30/2020', getdate())
```

Comment: You asked this [59 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145344/why-is-the-sql-datediff-function-rounding-up). Don't delete questions and repost them.

Comment: Take some time to read the documentation. It explains the function *"returns the count ... of the specified datepart **boundaries** crossed between [the two dates]..."* Boundaries <> complete months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```
declare @start date 
declare @end date
set @start = '6/30/2020'
set @end = '2/16/2022'
select datediff(month, dateadd(day, -day(@start)+1, @start), dateadd(day, -day(@start)+1,@end))
```

[link to fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cc943727973f48633bf25a18ed42de70)

Comment: Is this an answer, or something else? It reads like it's addition information to go in your question.

Comment: @larnu this is the answer that worked for me.

Comment: Then I would suggest you [edit] your answer to actually make it look like an answer. Explaining what it does goes a long way. Code dump answers can often not be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation[SQL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), datediff returns
*The int difference between the startdate and enddate, expressed in the boundary set by datepart.*
which in your example is the number of months from June '20 to February '22 which is indeed 20. User user716255's code is pointing into the right direction in that it uses the first of each month in question. If your intention however is to really know how many months elapsed between two dates, the code should be amended like so:
(sorry, need to correct my original answer, as I misread the code from the other answer)

```
declare @start date 
declare @end date
set @start = '20200630'
set @end = '20220216'
select datediff(month, dateadd(day, -day(@start)+1, @start), dateadd(day, - 
day(@end)+1,@end))+CASE WHEN DAY(@end)>DAY(@start) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

(with dates written in a format more useful for our international readers...)
The original coude would fail if start date would i.e. be 31st of July and the end date in February (as -31+1 would lead to a date in January)

Comment: your function returns 20 instead of 19. There are 19 months between 6/30/2020 and 2/16/2022. The ask was how do I modify the code , so that SQL would count months as date/month unit.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was given far to hastily...
Please try
`DECLARE @start date 
DECLARE @end date
SET @start = '20200630'
SET @end = '20220216'
SELECT
  (year(@end)*12+month(@end))-(year(@start)*12+month(@start)) as pureDateDiffExplained,
  datediff(month, @start,@end) as pureDateDiff, 
  datediff(month, dateadd(day, -day(@start)+1, @start), dateadd(day, -day(@end)+1,@end))-CASE WHEN DAY(@end)<DAY(@start) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as dateDiffCorrected`

Comment: @ub_coding - Please add that code as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71146298/why-is-the-sql-datediff-function-rounding-up) to your answer, then delete the comment.  That much code is unreadable in comments. Plus comments get deleted.